# Need to associate the listener with enter button in Java 2 Micro Edition

Tags: java, java-me

I am developing a J2ME application for Windows CE Mobile Device manufactured by Motorola (MC70) and running this application over IBM J9 JVM. Most of the application is over and I am stuck in one region

I.e; I will enter the value in the text field and that value needs to be validated by invoking other midlet / class (I achieved this by adding a command to the form and validating the data) but the main problem is the key board is having an enter button and I require to validate the text field value when i press the enter button. I tried a lot by using canvas / listeners but there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch any key inputs with JavaME in `Form`s.
How the high level GUI is presented and edited, is device-dependent. Meaning, it'll look differently on different devices. The Enter key is not there on other devices, for example.

Some might say you could implement your own field using `Canvas` or `GameCanvas`, but then you'd also have to implement your own key-input function. That's a lot of work.

Another option is to look into LWUIT. I have no experience with LWUIT myself, but I know it's very popular, and offers a lot of UI stuff like `Form` does - but LWUIT is built on `Canvas`/`GameCanvas`, so there's a chance it offers what you're looking for. Check it out.

Comment: Or else can i grab the key pressed event using any key listener

Comment: Yes, but that won't work on high level GUI (`Form` stuff). That's why I say `Canvas` or `GameCanvas`.

Comment: Once again thank you i got the solution using canvas and the key for enter button is Game_Fire